# Retrieving CLOB objects from JDBC ResultSet taking lot time

Tags: jdbc, resultset, clob

We have standalone application connecting using JDBC to Oracle Datatbase. I am retrieving values for past one month, where resultset may vary from 25,000 to 100,000 records per month.
When iterating ResultSet, i am retrieving 3 String(varchar) columns and 3 CLOB columns.
When resultset is even 25,000 records, iterating resultset is taking around 6 hours of time. When i comment CLOB objects retrieval time taken is just few minutes, for 25,000 records.
I tried both ways of retrieving CLOB objects using java.sql.CLOB and oracle.sql.CLOB, both take same amount of time. 
Any ways of enhancing the performance, please suggest.
Java version : 1.6
Oracle :10g
ojdbc14.jar

Comment: Why are you using the Java 1.4 driver with Java 6, and are you sure you are using the latest? Also how large are these clobs?

Comment: Clob objects differe from 2000 to 4000 char. Using JDBC 1.6 driver does it make difference? In terms of retrieval speed?

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, I just suggest that you try the latest driver that matches your Java version.

Comment: Hi Mark.. I used JDBC 1.6 driver as per suggestion, but i am still facing the same problem. Any other details i need to look into?